Is it possible to set the Julia compiler (llvm?) optimization level?
I am currently running some Julia script from the command line using:
julia --project=text-env main.jl --optimize=3

I am not sure what the default optimization level is, or if it can even be changed in this way.
Running this command does not produce any error or warning, but I do not know if the flag --optimize=3 is doing anything.
The runtime performance of my code is approximately 5 seconds, regardless of how I set the optimization level. I have also tried --optimize=0.
I believe LLVM can optimize the generated code with different levels of optimization.
The only reference I have found relating to this is from the discourse, and it wasn't clear to me whether or not LLVM could be configured in this way using a command line flag.

https://discourse.julialang.org/t/julia-optimization-levels-and-the-case-for-less-optimization-slower-faster-compilation/105375

